# meta_value timestamp older than now

Tags: posts, wp-query, query, wpdb

In my `wp_posts` table I want to select the rows `where post_type == event`. I also want to a connection with `wp_postmeta` from the specific row. In my `wp_postmeta` table I want to do a where like this: `Where post_id == (post id from wp_posts) and the meta_value from meta_key == event_date_end_timestamp is older than now`.

So in my wp_postmeta I have :
[image]

But how can I form my query to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'event_date_end_timestamp',
            'value'   => time(),
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<'
        )
    )
);

$programs = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php while($programs->have_posts()): $programs->the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```